# julia: @timev differing values for bytes allocated

Tags: memory, julia

Is it better to use [@allocated](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@allocated) versus "bytes allocated" for measuring memory usage?  I'm a bit surprised that bytes allocated changes from invocation to invocation.

```
julia> @timev map(x->2*x, [1:100])
  0.047360 seconds (89.54 k allocations: 4.269 MiB)
elapsed time (ns): 47359831
bytes allocated:   4476884
pool allocs:       89536
non-pool GC allocs:1
1-element Array{StepRange{Int64,Int64},1}:
 2:2:200

julia> @timev map(x->2*x, [1:100])
  0.047821 seconds (89.56 k allocations: 4.271 MiB)
elapsed time (ns): 47820714
bytes allocated:   4478708
pool allocs:       89554
non-pool GC allocs:1
1-element Array{StepRange{Int64,Int64},1}:
 2:2:200

julia> @timev map(x->2*x, [1:100])
  0.045273 seconds (89.58 k allocations: 4.274 MiB)
elapsed time (ns): 45272518
bytes allocated:   4481108
pool allocs:       89580
non-pool GC allocs:1
1-element Array{StepRange{Int64,Int64},1}:
 2:2:200
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should read the performance tips section of the Julia manual: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html

You are violating tip number one: don't benchmark in global scope. A big red flag should be that this simple operation takes 4/100 of a second and allocates 4MB.

For benchmarking, always use the BenchmarkTools.jl package. Below is example usage.

(BTW, do you really mean to operate on `[1:100]`? This is a single-element vector, where the single element is a Range object. Did you perhaps intend to work on `1:100` or maybe `collect(1:100)`?)

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> foo(y) = map(x->2*x, y)
foo (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> v = 1:100
1:100

julia> @btime foo($v)
  73.372 ns (1 allocation: 896 bytes)

julia> v = collect(1:100);

julia> @btime foo($v);
  73.699 ns (2 allocations: 912 bytes)

julia> @btime foo($v);
  73.100 ns (2 allocations: 912 bytes)

julia> @btime foo($v);
  74.033 ns (2 allocations: 912 bytes)

julia> v = [1:100];

julia> @btime foo($v);
  55.563 ns (2 allocations: 128 bytes)
```

As you can see, runtimes are almost 6 orders of magnitude faster than what you are seeing, and allocations are stable.

Notice also that the last example, which uses `[1:100]`, is faster than the others, but that's because it's doing something else.